# How to produce date object using moment.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs

How to produce a similar `new Date()` object using moment.js?

I have input as UTC date and output should be similar to `new Date()` object. 
Please help to resolve this.

```
Input: 1389033000000
Output: Tue Jan 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`moment().format(pattern)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), where `pattern` is a string describing the format you want.

Something like this should work:

```
const input = 1389033000000
const output = moment(input).format("ddd MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss ZZ")

console.log(output)
// Mon Jan 06 2014 04:30:00 GMT-0200

console.log(new Date(input))
// Mon Jan 06 2014 16:30:00 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)
```

Furthermore, you can convert a moment to native date with [`moment().toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/)

```
const input = 1389033000000
const output = moment(input).toDate()

console.log(output)
// Mon Jan 06 2014 16:30:00 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to convert time to particular timezone

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var timestamp =  1389033000000;
var usingTimezone = moment(timestamp).tz("Asia/Kolkata").format("ddd MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss Z");
var usingOffset = moment(timestamp).utcOffset("+05:30").format("ddd MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss Z");

console.log(usingTimezone);
console.log(usingOffset);
```